# Composition of the Continuity[Topology]

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove the statement I've made myself.

There are three topological spaces, $(X_1, T_1)$, $(X_2, T_2)$ and $(X_3, T_3)$. Put $G_i$ be a open set of the each $(X_i, T_i)$

Say the $f: (X_1, T_1) \to (X_2, T_2)$ and $g: (X_2, T_2) \to (X_3, T_3)$

Then Is the below statement holds?

Statement) Both $f$ and $g$ are continuous $\iff $ $g\circ f : (X_1, T_1) \to (X_3, T_3)$ is continuous.

In the case of the direction "$\Rightarrow$"

$g\circ f$ is continuous because $f^{-1}(G_1) \in T_1$ and $f^{-1}(G_2) \in T_2$ for $\forall G_1, G_2$

So I could easily conclude the  $(g\circ f)^{-1} (G_3) \in T_1$ (I.e. continuous)

But the case of the opposite direction "$\Leftarrow$", I haven't caught neither any idea proving it nor any counterexample.

Any help would be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Take a constant function $g$. then $g\circ f$ is continuous for any $f$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "no", even when $g=f$. Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean topology and

$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if }x\geq 0 \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

and note that $f$ is not continuous. But $f(f(x))=1$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and thus $f\circ f$ is continuous.

I leave as an exercise (by tweaking this example) that $g\circ f$ being continuous doesn't say anything about the continuity of neither $g$ nor $f$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Kavi Rama Murthy said in commnet, you can see $(g \circ f)$ can be continuous ignoring $f$, if $g$ be constant.

For another example consider $(X_1,T_1)$ with discrete topology, then $(g \circ f)$ becomes continuous ignoring $g$.